# Не присваивается значение переменной PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qtextedit

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой,что `getIP1` не передает значение в `self.textEdit_2.setText`.

Я пробовал принтовать переменную `getIP1`, все нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    def Whois(self):
        getIP = self.lineEdit.text()
        url = "https://ipinfo.io/" + getIP + "/json"
        try:
            getInfo = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            infoList = json.load(getInfo)
            geIP1 = ("IP: ", infoList["ip"])
            self.textEdit_2.setText(geIP1)
        except:
            pass
```

```
import urllib.request
import json
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(2417, 957)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2421, 921))
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(801, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 22, 111, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 15, 431, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2417, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_2.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Whois Function"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_6.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Port Scanner "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_4.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Blacklists checkout "))


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Whois)



    def Whois(self):
        getIP = self.lineEdit.text()
        url = "https://ipinfo.io/" + getIP + "/json"
        try:
            getInfo = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            infoList = json.load(getInfo)
            geIP1 = ("IP: ", infoList["ip"])
            self.textEdit_2.setText(geIP1)
        except:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: что надо набрать в `lineEdit`, чтобы получить правильный `url`

Comment: IP адрес,который вставляется в ссылку,после этого ссылка преобразовывается в формат json который мне надо вставить в TextEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QTextEdit::setText(const QString &text)
>
> Устанавливает текст редактирования текста. Текст может быть простым текстом или HTML.

а вы передавали кортеж

```
import urllib.request
import json
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1300, 600)                                       #(2417, 957)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2421, 921))
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(801, 0))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 22, 111, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 15, 431, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(36, 20, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 40, 441, 291))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 441, 20))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 302, 111, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 2417, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_2.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Whois Function"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_6.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Port Scanner "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "               IP"))
        self.label_4.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "                                                              Work place"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch!"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Blacklists checkout "))


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.whois)



    def whois(self):
        getIP = self.lineEdit.text()
        url = "https://ipinfo.io/" + getIP + "/json"
        try:
            getInfo = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            infoList = json.load(getInfo)
            
#            geIP1 = ("IP: ", infoList["ip"])                        # ---
            geIP1 = (f'IP: {infoList["ip"]}')                        # +++
                
            self.textEdit_2.setText(geIP1)
#        except:                                                     # ---
        except Exception as e:                                       # +++
            self.textEdit_2.append(f'Error: {e}')                    # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]